# Cannot find `ZipArchive` in the “System.IO.Compression” namespace

Tags: c#, reference, .net-4.5, assemblies

My question is related to [I didn't find "ZipFile" class in the "System.IO.Compression" namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241889/i-didnt-find-zipfile-class-in-the-system-io-compression-namespace)

[image: The type or namespace name 'ZipArchive' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO.Compression']

But I have referenced the DLL's for my 4.5.1 webforms project:

[image: Screenshot of 'References' tab]

Properties of my project give me: `Target framework: .Net Framework 4.5.1.`
and the web.config:

```xml
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

What am I missing?

The solution was to manually reference the assemblies in the web.config But why? Why wasn't the checkbox in the add reference dialog insufficient?

```xml
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</assemblies>
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20099950/169714) to "Installed .Net 4.5 but can't use ZipFile class in Visual C#"

Comment: Are you getting any other message during compiling (such as assembly missing)? Output window might be useful.

Comment: You also need a reference to the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem. Whether or you checked is not visible.

Comment: I have added the reference and it still gave me the assembly missing message. Adding the two lines in the web.config fixed it. But why? Normally is the add reference dialog sufficient.

Answer (score 23):

I faced same problem because the namespace is not present in References,Please do the following steps.

**In my case Without References**

[image: When References not installed]

**After Installing References**

[image]
**Solution**

1)Install system.Io.compression from nuget here

[System.IO.Compression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Compression/)

2)Install system.Install-Package 40-System.IO.Compression.FileSystem from nuget here.

[System.IO.Compression.FileSystem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/40-System.IO.Compression.FileSystem/)

Answer (score 22):

you can update References in Project file directly (Unload Project and Edit this or open .csproj file with notepad and edit)

**Before** edit must same as:

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" />
```

**After** your edit:

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

load again your project in Visual Studio and rebuild it. I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I fixed it 2 years ago. Can you explain why the edit in the csproj fixes it?

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var zip = new ZipArchive(System.IO.File.OpenRead(zipFileName))) { ... }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.