# get archive file list recursively

Tags: c#, powershell, archive, 7zip

For example, I have an archive called test.zip.

I would like it to be listed all files in this archive and archives inside it without unzipping.

- test.zip

  - 1.txt
  - 2.txt
  - subarchive.zip

    - 3.txt
    - 4.txt
  - somedir

    - 5.txt

Preferably do this on C # or Powershell.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first take look at the ZipArchive class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx

If you have trouble to directly put the class into use like me there might be missing a ZipArchive reference.

As explained by user5093161 on this post: [Cannot find `ZipArchive` in the “System.IO.Compression” namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802239/cannot-find-ziparchive-in-the-system-io-compression-namespace?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) you might install the two following NuGet packages.

1. NuGet System.IO.Compression
2. NuGet 40-System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

A first approach can be to show the full name of every entry, e.g.:

```
public void ZipTesting()
{
    string zipPath = @"c:\zipTest\TestArchive.zip";
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) library as following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(@"d:\test.zip"))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.IsDirectory);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another version for traversing the archive based on the System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive Class

```
static void OutputEntries(ZipArchive archive) {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);

            if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".zip")) {

                ZipArchive embeddedZipArchive = new ZipArchive(entry.Open());
                OutputEntries(embeddedZipArchive);

            }
        }
```

like @Faenrig already pointed

> If you have trouble to directly put the class into use like me there
>   might be missing a ZipArchive reference.
>
> As explained by user5093161 on this post: Cannot find `ZipArchive` in
>   the “System.IO.Compression” namespace you might install the two
>   following NuGet packages.
>
> NuGet System.IO.Compression NuGet 40-System.IO.Compression.FileSystem